# "She bore a child" vs "She gave birth to a child"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, informal-writing

The sentence *"She gave birth to a child"* or *"She had a child"* is normal.
But the verb *‘bear‘* also means *‘to give birth to young‘*.
Therefore, is the sentence *"She bore a child"* grammatically acceptable (though we‘re very unlikely to find it in usual speech or informal writing)?

Comment: Yes, it's grammatically acceptable. But it's pragmatically weird, and marks its speaker or writer as weird also.

Comment: "I bore him a child" sounds like a *duty*.

Comment: I am not quite convinced it is weird, but it is archaic. Ngram shows a peak in usage in the mid 1800s, much of it religious and related to Mary’s bearing Jesus.

Comment: @Anton It appears in quite a lot of traditional ballads going back well before the mid 1800s. For example the possibly sixteenth century Scottish ballad "Four Marys" which has the line "Mary Hamilton's born a babe to the highest Stuart of all" and "Bogey's Bonny Belle" (which _is_ nineteeth century) has the line "when nine long months had passed and gone she bore to me a son". I do suspect, though that there is some relationship between  "bearing a child" and "a child being born".

Comment: @BoldBen - Of course there is, because _borne_ is the past tense of _bear_; it's just that we now spell it without the 'e' when referring to birth. Nothing 'weird' about it, it's just formal and archaic.

Comment: @KateBunting I'm not saying that there's anything odd about it but the word "born" in relation to a child (or, later, an adult as in "Solomon Grundy, born on a Monday") seems to have been a separate word from "bourne" for a very long time and to relate to the act of birth rather than the reference to the mother having "bourne" or, in modern parlance "carried" the child through the entire pregnancy. I wonder when the two neanings started to separate, it seems to have been a long time ago. The line in Four Marys refers to the point of birth rather than to the pregnancy.

Comment: @BoldBen - That remark was in response to earlier comments that it was, or was not, 'weird'. To 'bear' a child definitely refers to the birth and not the pregnancy, however.  Oxford describes the usage as _Formal, literary'. See [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/borne-vs-born-difference-usage-spelling#:~:text=Both%20born%20and%20borne%20are,almost%20too%20cute%20to%20bear.)

Comment: @WeatherVane - It could also mean that she did him a favor and gave him a son/daughter.

Comment: @KateBunting Sorry, I was being too self-absorbed! I agree, nothing weird about it, at least on our side of the pond!

Comment: Where are are any of you getting this, please? "She bore a child" might be a little old-fashioned but it's not remotely 'archaic.' Who doubts that, ask three native-English speaking midwives…

Answer (score -1):

You're right. It is fully grammatical, but it sounds like old fashioned literary English.

Answer (score -1):

It is a very biblical expression. Note that, interestingly enough, ***she bore a son*** is much more common than ***she bore a child***. In the KJV you will find it in the form:

> She ***bare a son***. (Gen. 4:25 KJV)
>
> And Sarah my master's wife ***bare a son*** to my master when she was old: (Gen. 24:36 KJV)

<sub>*(**[Bare](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bare)** is the archaic past tense of **bear**)*</sub>

***Bare a son*** is used 22 times in the KJV, whereas the English translation of the Septuagint (beginning of 1800's) uses ***bore a son***.

While it is very true that in normal contexts it sounds dated, even obsolete, I am fascinated to see its frequency nowadays. ***She bore a son*** has the upper hand and is currently skyrocketing. But when you look at the results in [google.books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22she%20bore%20a%20son%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsYDQGA19TK3NfSiH907D-o-AdR8MQ:1660766114922&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKx9by0875AhVvQEEAHbm6CnYQpwV6BAgBECg&biw=1536&bih=743&dpr=1.25), they almost exclusively refer to the Bible.

[image]

So although it is correct and more common that we would expect, unless your context has religious connotations or you want to sound Victorian, it's safe to use the normal ***She gave birth to a child.***